# SimpleOnGestureListener not working

Tags: java, android, android-gesture

I want to change between activities by swiping in my **MainActivity**. I declared an object from **GestureDetectorCompat** and initialized it in method **onCreate** like that:

```
gestureObject = new GestureDetectorCompat(MainActivity.this, new GestureListener());
```

Also, I override **onTouchEvent** like that:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.gestureObject.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

and my **MainActivity** extends from **AppCompatActivity** and implements **NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMenuItemClickListener**.

GestureListener code is:

```
private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "long pressed");
        super.onLongPress(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        Log.e(TAG, "on Flig");

        if (e2.getX() > e1.getX()) {

            Log.e(TAG, "left to right");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

but it does not work.

Is it related to **navigationView**?

What can I do?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Comment: I have activity, not fragment.

Comment: How does it not work: crashes, error messages, freezes, unexpected behaviour or hordes of locusts?

Comment: Do not anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code..

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(MainActivity.this, new SwipeGestureDetector());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    return mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

/**
 * Swipe Gesture Detector Class for swipe detector.
 */
public class SwipeGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if(e1 == null || e2 == null)
            return false;
        if(e1.getPointerCount() > 1 || e2.getPointerCount() > 1)
            return false;
        else {
            try {
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                if(Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > 100 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 1000) {
                        if ((diffX > 0) || (diffX < 0)) {
//                                      nextActivity();

                                return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Send me full code with all listener (NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMenuItemClickListener.) So, i can figure out where is problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.gestureObject.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
```